# PHP order form, repopulate "selected" drop downs

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

Hope that title actually describes the issue.

Got a form in 3 steps, user can go from step 2 to step 1, to change details.

So far every input is repopulating perfectly apart from multiple select drop downs.

I've been trying with `switch()` inside the `foreach()` of the array but it seems to stop when it matches the first case. I've changed `break;` to `continue;` but same behaviour exists.

The array is combined from 2, with the `$key` being item number and `$value` being item value.

The item `$value` outputs perfectly once per `foreach()`.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
    foreach($combined as $key => $value) {
           //firstload is only valid on first load
                  if($value != firstload) {

                    switch($value){
                    case "1":
                       $selected0 = "selected=\"selected\"";
                       break;
                    case "5.00":
                       $selected1 = "selected=\"selected\"";
                       break;
                    case "10.00":
                       $selected2 = "selected=\"selected\"";
                       break;
                    case "45.00":
                       $selected3 = "selected=\"selected\"";
                       break;
                    case "85.00":
                       $selected4 = "selected=\"selected\"";
                       break;
                                        }
```

Then the HTML select options `<option value="5.00" $selected1">` etc.

When switch matches a case, it then matches that case for every foreach.

Comment: Could we see the exact code snippet?

Comment: you should post your code - just the relevant parts, preferably commented and I am sure someone will help you

Comment: I think we need more code. Because this code doesn't really have a problem with it, besides the missing ending `}` but I'll assume that is a typo.

Comment: It's a tricky one to explain. switch() is matching multiple times, so multiple options are being given the attr selected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this could help you, with no code to work on - but here is an idea you could rewrite to your needs.

```
<select name="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
<?php
    // Could come from sessions or POST data
    $selected_array = array("1", "10.00", "85.00");

    // Could come from database or something else
    $multiple_select_values = array("1", "5.00", "10.00", "45.00", "85.00");

    foreach($multiple_select_values as $value) {
        $selected = "";
        if(in_array($value, $selected_array))
            $selected = " selected=\"selected\"";

        echo '<option value="'. $value . '"' . $selected. '>' . $value .'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this, I seem to suck at explaining the issue. I've got it working using `elseif`, it's not pretty though. Once again thanks.